# Retrieve data from dynamodb using pynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, pynamodb

I'm getting started with pynamodb (and dynamodb), and can't figure out how to use it.

I have:

- A dynamodb table
- A lambda

Running this code inside a lambda, I can successfully create two entries (I see them in the dynamodb Management Console):

```
class User(Model):
        class Meta:
            table_name = dynamodb_table_name
            region = "eu-west-1"

        email = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
        first_name = UnicodeAttribute(null=False)
        last_name = UnicodeAttribute(null=False)

User(email="john@snow.com", first_name="John", last_name="Snow").save()
User(email="danny@targaryen.com", first_name="Daenerys", last_name="Targaryen").save()
```

I then attempt to retrieve one of these entries, running the following code:

```
class User(Model):
        class Meta:
            table_name = "dynamodb_table_name"
            region = "eu-west-1"

        email = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
        first_name = UnicodeAttribute(null=False)
        last_name = UnicodeAttribute(null=False)
        
print(User.count())
jon = User.get("john@snow.com")
print(jon)
```

Here's the output I get:

```
0
dynamodb_table_name<None>
```

Questions:

- Why do `User.count()` returns zero, when I can clearly see two entries from the Management Console?
- Why can't the user be retrieved from the DB?

Comment: Not sure but Is there any chance your second snippet may be over-riding it?

Comment: Please provide a complete, runable code example and not just such a snippets, as the bug might be in code not included right now.

Comment: your fist snippet and second snippet has difference. first has `table_name =dynamodb_table_name` and second has `table_name = "dynamodb_table_name"`